# Vs no me muestra el mensaje que quiero imprimir con archivo py

Tags: python, vscode

me llamo Jhon Castañeda y actualmente estoy empezando con el tema de programación y python, estoy en lo basico y cuando intento imprimir un mensaje en VS me sale que se esta ejecutando pero no me sale el mensaje, ni la operacion deseada en mi caso.
Ya tengo la extension de python instalada junto con "prettier" y "python indent". Ya tengo python registrado en las variables de entorno, desinstale y me asegure de marcar "Add python 3.X to PATH", pero aun persiste y quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal. Agradezco mucho la información, saludo desde Colombia.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esa salida no esta en la terminal? o en otro lado?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Yo, como usuario de vscode, miro los resultados en la terminal.

Comment: Los resultados de este tipo van a salir en la pestaña de **TERMINAL**. En tu imagen se ve dicha pestaña. La de salida simplemente informa de si la ejecución ha tenido éxito o no, pero no muestra los valores del código como tal